Should you use __pc fields in all cases for Person Accounts?
We have Person Accounts set up in my organisation. For some reason, when they were first set up, instead of using the __pc fields for Person Account Page Layouts, we have created new, custom Account fields, and used them instead.
E.g.:
On the Contact object, there would be:
Nickname | nickname__c
On the Organisation object, there would be:
Nickname | nickname__pc
Nickname (Person Account) | nickname_new__c
With 'Nickname (Person Account)' being used on the Page Layouts for Person Accounts.
I am trying to figure out why it was done this way. It means we have more custom fields, and information is being held in two places. Is there a reason I'm missing here?

We can't really answer "why" in this case. Maybe there was a limitation where custom Person Account fields couldn't appear in some contexts, like reports or formulas, or perhaps not available in some kinds of integration or customization. It's well known that Person Accounts were considered "second-class citizens" in Salesforce for a long time. For years, each new Release Notes that were published would show off new features, with a specific limitation that the features wouldn't work with Person Accounts. Or, maybe someone just needed, or so they thought, business accounts that had a nickname, for some reason.
Ultimately, you'll need to analyze your data yourself. How many records have the Nickname_New__c field populated? Do any integrations, customizations, or code use this field? What is the risk of removing this field, or leaving them desynchronized? As a best practice, you certainly should only have one field, and it should be the Person Account field (Nickname__pc). However, virtually all best practices have an exception to the rule. After all, the real world is messy, and sometimes things need to be less-than-optimal.
